# Pythonic way of not printing a error message up

Tags: python, exception, warnings

I am trying to suppress a error/warning in my log while calling a library. Assume i have this code

```
        try:
            kazoo_client.start()
        except:
            pass
```

This is calling a zookeeper client which throws some exception which bubble up, now i don't want the warn/error in my logs when i call `kazoo_client.start()` is there a way to get this suppressed when you call the client

Comment: read documentation for module [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial)

Comment: @furas i know about that , this thing is i just want to do some magic on `kazoo_client.start()` and not any other place

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming python 2.7.17**

Try this approach:

```
import sys, StringIO

def funky() :
 "1" + 1 # This should raise an error

sys.stderr = StringIO.StringIO()
funky() # this should call the funky function
```

And your code should look something like this:

```
import sys, StringIO

# import kazoo somehere around here

sys.stderr = StringIO.StringIO()
kazoo_client.start()
```

And lastly the **Python 3** example:

```
import sys
from io import StringIO
# import kazoo somehere around here

sys.stderr = StringIO()
kazoo_client.start()
```

Comment: yes this is good! but now my actuall issue is out but i see `Unhandled exception in thread started by` 

still

Answer (score 0):

If you know the exception, try [`contextlib.suppress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.suppress):

```
>>> from contextlib import suppress
>>> x = (i for i in range(10))
>>> with suppress(StopIteration):
...     for i in range(11):
...         print(next(x))

0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Without suppress it throws `StopIteration` error at last iteration.

```
>>> x = (i for i in range(10))

>>> for i in range(11):
...     print(next(x))

0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-10-562798e05ad5>", line 2, in <module>
    print(next(x))

StopIteration
```

Suppress is Pythonic, safe and explicit.

So in your case:

```
with suppress(SomeError):
    kazoo_client.start()
```

**EDIT:**

To suppress all exceptions:

```
with suppress(Exception):
    kazoo_client.start()
```

Comment: i think i still see the warning in print, i hoping if we can pass `SomeError` as any Exception

Comment: Nope didn't helped. am i missing something

Comment: Edited, could you check?

Comment: still not suppressed :(

Comment: Are you sure the exception is coming from this line itself? Could you paste the exception you are getting?

Comment: Yes it is also i see in the doc , that context.supress is equivalent to doing try except, which i am already doing

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest a more generic approach, which can be used in general.
I leave you an example of how to create an decorator who ignore errors.

```
import functools


# Use the Decorator Design Pattern

def ignore_error_decorator(function_reference):
    @functools.wraps(function_reference)  # the decorator inherits the original function signature
    def wrapper(*args):
        try:
            result = function_reference(*args)  # execute the function
            return result  # If the function executed correctly, return
        except Exception as e:
            pass  # Default ignore; You can also log the error or do what ever you want

    return wrapper  # Return the wrapper reference


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # First alternative to use. Compose the decorator with another function
    def my_first_function(a, b):
        return a + b

    rez_valid = ignore_error_decorator(my_first_function)(1, 3)
    rez_invalid = ignore_error_decorator(my_first_function)(1, 'a')
    print("Alternative_1 valid: {result}".format(result=rez_valid))
    print("Alternative_1 invalid: {result}".format(result=rez_invalid)) # None is return by the exception bloc

    # Second alternative. Decorating a function
    @ignore_error_decorator
    def my_second_function(a, b):
        return a + b


    rez_valid = my_second_function(1, 5)
    rez_invalid = my_second_function(1, 'a')
    print("Alternative_2 valid: {result}".format(result=rez_valid))
    print("Alternative_2 invalid: {result}".format(result=rez_invalid))  # None is return by the exception bloc
```

**Getting back to your problem, using my alternative you have to run**

```
ignore_error_decorator(kazoo_client.start)()
```